# Getting HTML of dynamic websites with BeautifulSoup and requests

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

keyword = "dog"
url = f"https://www.pinterest.de/search/pins/?q={keyword}&rs=typed&term_meta[]={keyword}%7Ctyped"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content)
print(r)
```

Output: `<Response [200]>`

If i change the `print(r)` to `print(soup)`, i get a lot of text that dosen't look like HTML.

Something like: `..."marketing_brand_charlotte_phoenix":"control","marketing_brand_houston_chicago":"enabled","marketing_brand_houston_miami_business":"enabled","marketing_brand_northnhinenestphalia_bavaria":"enabled","marketing_brand_northrhinewestphalia_bavaria_business":"enabled","marketing_brand_seattle_dallas_business":"control","marketing_brand_seattle_orlando":"control","merchant_discovery_shopify_boosting":"control","merchant_storefront_mojito_migration":"enabled","merchant_success_activation_banner_collapse_over_dismiss":"enabled","merchant_success_auto_enroll_approved_merchant":"enabled","merchant_success_catalog_activation_card_copy_update":"control","merchant_success_claim_your_website_copy_update":"control","merchant_success_i18n_umr_review_flag":"enabled","merchant_success_product_tagging":"enabled","merchant_success_switch_merchant_review_queues":"enabled","merchant_success_tag_activation_card_copy_update":"control","merchant_success_tag_installation_redirect":"enabled","merchant_success_unified_merchant_review":"enabled","mini_renux_homefeed_refresh":"enabled","more_ideas_email_notifications":"enabled","more_ideas_newshub_notifications":"enabled","more_ideas_push_notifications":"enabled","msft_pwa_announcement_email":"control","multi_format_ad_group":"enabled","mweb_account_switcher_v2":"enabled","mweb_advertiser_growth_add_biz_create_entrypoint":"enabled","mweb_all_profiles_follow_parity":"enabled","mweb_auth_android_lite_low_res_limit_width":"enabled_736x","mweb_auth_low_res_limit_width":"enabled_736x","mweb_auth_no_client_context":"enabled"...`

How can I get the HTLM to then eventually scrape the pictures of a page depending on the `keyword`? And how to handle endless pages when scraping?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right page if you request it properly. The servers, to prevent from scraping, use some basic checks to filter them. So the problem concerns only the request not the scraping part. The first and cheapest attempt is pass a "fake" user agent to your request.

```
user_agent = # of firefox, chrome, safari, opera,...
response = requests.get(url, headers={ "user-agent": user_agent})
```